# .pot file is overwritten everytime gettext.extract() is executed - old translations lost

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-gettext

I'm using [angular-gettext](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/) to have a multi-language app in AngularJS

I cannot find the way to maintain the old translations and not overwrite them every time I extract them.

here is of my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gettext = require('gulp-angular-gettext');

gulp.task('translations:parse', function () {
return gulp.src([conf.paths.src + '/app/**/*.html', conf.paths.src + '/app/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(gettext.extract('translations.pot', {}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.src + '/app/translations/'));
});
```

So the first time the file "translations.pot" is generated. If I make the translations directly in this file, and then run `gulp translations:parse` again, the translations saved in "translations.pot" will be lost.

So let's say I have in `translations.pot`

```
#: partials/home.html:3
msgid "Welcome"
msgstr "Bienvenido"
```

After running `gulp translations:parse` again, the translations are lost

```
#: partials/home.html:3
msgid "Welcome"
msgstr ""
```

Is there any possible solution for that? How can I save the old translations?

Thanks a lot
Adrián Bolonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received an answer from the developer in [GitHub](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext-tools/issues/113)

> You're not meant to edit the .pot file, it's a template for updating your .po files.
>
> Here's a guide on how to do translations correctly: https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/translate/

So problem solved :)